# "would" as a possibility?

Tags: meaning

Case 1)
A : That girl with Mike. who is she?
B: That would be his sister.

Case 2)
A : I saw a guy who has a british accent. And he goes to your school.
B : That would be Brad.

can "would" be used as a possibility ?

Comment: In both these examples it means 'That is who it is most likely to be.' In (2), B hasn't seen the person in question but suggests that Brad fits the description. In (1), perhaps B doesn't know Mike's sister but has reason to believe that the girl with him is her.

Comment: Yes. It can be thought of as equivalent to _If you were to ask me, I would tell you that ..._ It's a form of distancing oneself from taking responsibility for one's statements that modals allow. For instance, it is a much stronger assertion to say _She is Mike's sister_ than to say _She must be Mike's sister_. Even if it's a strong probability, it's only a probability and not certainty. Modals are very useful that way.